# Why has my keyboard change layout settings?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with my keyboard set to the UK layout. It's worked fine for the past few months but today it seems to enter characters from the US keyboard layout (ie @ instead of ").

I thought maybe it was simply that the keyboard layout settings had been reset from an update or something. But when I go to Settings > Text Entry - the only keyboard configuration I have is English (UK). If I go to the keyboard layout chart all of the keys seem to be correctly located.

Where are the files where these settings are kept and how can I edit them if they turn out to be wrong?

I have no idea why this would have changed. The only thing I can think of is that in Software & Updates I selected other... and told it to find the best server as I have recently changed location. It set my update location to server in Hong Kong.

Comment: try this `setxkbmap gb` in terminal

Comment: Perfect, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Set your updates back to servers in the UK. Hong Kong servers cannot download updates in the UK keyboard layout. Besides, Canonical HQ is in the UK, so it is likely the servers in the UK are best.